# Python and Django Blog Sample Project

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views

I am newbie to python as well as Django, and I have started a sample project "blog".

Currently blog posts are added to the database manually, but I want to do it at front end by providing a form to the user. I created my `model.py` and `views.py` files, but I am unable to see these fields on the front end. I have copied all of my code below:

**models.py**:

```
class posts(models.Model): 
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 30) 
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100) 
    bodytext = models.TextField() 
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField() 

class postForm(ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
         model = posts
```

**views.py**:

```
def home(request):
    content = posts.objects.all()[:5]
    return render_to_response('index.html',{'posts' : content})

def save_blog(request):      
    form = postForm
    if request.POST:
        form = postForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save
    return render_to_response('index.html',{'form' : form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**url.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url    
from django.contrib import admin   
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns =
    patterns('',
        url(r'^$', 'blog.views.home', name='home'),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
    )
```

**index.html**:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Welcome To</h1>
        <hr />
        {% for post in posts %} 
            <div class="posts">
                <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
                <h3>Posted on {{ post.timestamp }} by {{ post.author }}</h3>
                <p>{{ post.bodytext }}</p>
            </div>
            <hr />
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="forms">
        <form action="." method="post" name="posts" id="posts">{% csrf_token %}
        <table>
        <tr><td>{{form.author.label}}</td><td>{{form.author}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{form.title.label}}</td><td>{{form.title}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{form.bodytext.label}}</td><td>{{form.bodytext}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><input type="button" name="btnSave" id="bntSave" value="Submit"  class = "default2"/></td>
        </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

**settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES**:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

Please let me know if i am missing anything. Also let me know how can I achieve this without using a Django model form.

Thanks

Comment: If you are new user, you must use spmething like this to name classes in python. see this http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Comment: The pattern for using a form in a view is explicitly given [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view). Why aren't you using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

views.py

```
def home(request):
     content = posts.objects.all()[:5]
     form = postForm() 
     if request.POST:
         form = postForm(request.POST) 
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
     return render_to_response('index.html',{'posts' : content, 'form' : form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

index.html

```
<div class="forms">
    <form method="post" name="posts" id="posts">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <input type="button" name="btnSave" id="bntSave" value="Submit" class="default2"/>    //<---------------
    </form>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

Ok I see it now why it's not submitting. You put `button` instead of `submit` in the input type

```
<input type="submit" name="btnSave" id="bntSave" value="Submit" class="default2"/> //<---------------
```

Just add `auto_now_add` in your timestamp field

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: I feel like just fixing people's code doesn't really help them especially without an explanation... I think it would make things worse (at least it would for me) because they end up copy-pasting instead of working through it.

Comment: i dont want to copy and paste ,nothing i am going to learn if i do that. so please do give explanation.

Comment: @catherine i hope you understood what i am trying to do here, actually def home is one function which is used to get data from backend and put it in index.html.
and save_blog is another function where i am trying to save html data to backend.
m i doing it correctly ?

Comment: Depends, which view are you accessing in the browser? The `home` view does not have the form in it.

Comment: @Razer I understand what are your trying to do. But your doing it wrong. You must defined the `postForm()` inside the home so that it will display the form. Understand?

Comment: @catherine hey its displaying those field now. i used your first method. but can you please tell me y you combined save_blog and home.
and what should be the form action value. i mean what value we assign to action ? 
i am trying to submit the form but its not submitting.

Comment: @catherine in many of the sites i have seen action as "." 
but i dont know why "." is actually used. what do we use here and what is the syntax ?

Comment: i dint define the action . but i am not able to submit

Comment: @catherine i am doing that,still it doesnt work!!

return render_to_response('index.html',{'posts' : content, 'form' : form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Comment: <form action="." method="POST" name="posts" id="posts">{% csrf_token %}
....................
</form>

Comment: url.py
**url(r'^$', 'blog.views.home', name='home'),**

Comment: @catherine everything seems to be correct but nothing happens when i submit.

Comment: @catherine i really dont see any error in that, and my template code is already posted above. i have not done any change in that.

Comment: @catherine Thanks alot. but i am still facing problems:( data isnt going to database.

Comment: @catherine its working fine now :) need one last help. actually i have 4 field and one of them is date field. i was not showing date field in the form thats why it was not inserting data to backend. 
but i dont want to show it and i want to assign value it in the view. how can i do that ?

Comment: @Razer I update my answer. What you need is in the bottom of my answer

Comment: @catherine hey i wanted to implement plagiarism using python and django? can you please suggest me how can i do it ? i dont want to store anything other den result in database, and den display the result in front page. input from user will be one text area and one file field.

Comment: @catherine http://smallseotools.com/plagiarism-checker/

plagiarism actually query google and return the result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you called your form `postForm` but are using `posts_form` in your view...

I also am unsure what `form_save` is, you should be calling [`save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) on the form instance like

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

And after posting, it is common practice to redirect the user to another url to prevent resubmitting data.

Comment: @Razer You should take a look at the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) posted by [Daniel Roseman](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896109/python-and-django-blog-sample-project/15896170#comment22637421_15896109)

Comment: i am trying that now
can anyone tell me what does this mean:
return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
why thanks is surrounded by /.../ and is thanks a html file ?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman
My New View Py Looks Lik This :

**def home(request):
    content = posts.objects.all()[:5]
    return render_to_response('index.html',{'posts' : content}) 
  
  
def save_blog(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = postForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') POST
    else:
        form = postForm() 

    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'form': form,
    })**

But its not showing those field in the template.

Comment: My New View Py Looks Lik This :

**def home(request):
    content = posts.objects.all()[:5]
    return render_to_response('index.html',{'posts' : content}) 
  
  
def save_blog(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = postForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') POST
    else:
        form = postForm() 

    return render(request, 'index.html', {
        'form': form,
    })**

But its not showing those field in the template.

Comment: @Razer It looks like you were able to get things working, but to answer your first question, `HttpResponseRedirect` simply returns a 302 response with a location header to redirect the browser. See here for more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect